# Facebook App oauth text change

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have searched all over web but did not find any single article about how to change the text of facebook app authorization dialog.

My app displays the following text on authorization.

*"This app would like to post to Facebook on you."*

But I want to change this into:

*"This APP WILL POST YOUR ENTRY ON YOUR FACEBOOK WALL"*

Kindly guide me for this. I am using PHP SDK

Comment: I think you're talking about the wording that shows up when the user is authorizing your app. If so, I don't think that text is editable by the implementing application for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Thanks @StevenV for the comment. Is there any other solution? can we use improved oauth dialog for facebook

Comment: That message is displayed by Facebook to the user to allow the user to understand what they are authorizing. I don't foresee them allowing you to change that message anytime soon across any of the authorization methods. A solution to that would be to have a message on your web page before authorization explaining to the user what you're asking them to do and why.